# How to get index of element has specific child using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have three div containers.

```
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box">
    <span class="item">my item</span>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

There's an item in one of the containers. How do I detect which container it is, i.e. first, second or third?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no need for a loop here, you can simply get the `index()` of the `.box` that contains the `.item` by selecting it directly:

```js
var index = $('.box .item').closest('.box').index('.box');
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box">
  <span class="item">my item</span>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this with an each loop and then you look up if the item element has a bigger length than 0. Please note that the counter starts at 0.

I made you an example which alerts the index of the element that contains something. If you want to start counting at 1 just write index+1 within the alert.

```
$(".box").each(function(index){
    if($(this).children(".item").length > 0){
      alert(index);
    }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/m1voxk6e/

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
$(".box").each(function(index,ele){

    if($(this).children().length > 0)

        alert("Div Number "  + (index + 1) + " have Item(s)");

})
```

Final code :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
    <body>
        
        <div class="box">

        </div>
        <div class="box">
            <span class="item">my item</span>
        </div>
        <div class="box">

        </div>
 
        
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
        
        <script>
            
        $(".box").each(function(index,ele){

            if($(this).children().length > 0)

                alert("Div Number "  + (index + 1) + " have Item(s)");

        })

 
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you could use the length property of the object

Ex:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    var obj=$(".box").children('.item');
    if(obj.length>0){
        //do something with the object
        alert(obj.parent().html());
        alert(obj.parent().index());
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box">

</div>
<div class="box">
    <span class="item">my item</span>
</div>
<div class="box">

</div>
```

Comment: This isn't what question want.

Comment: at the obj element you could use parent function... I edit the answer

Comment: Question is about get index of parent element.

Comment: is the same... change the html() for index()... this give you the number of index

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`:has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has-selector/) or [`.has()`](https://api.jquery.com/has/) to selecting `.box` element contain `.item`.

```
$(".box:has(.item)").index(".box");
// Or
$(".box").has(".item").index(".box");
```

```js
var index = $(".box:has(.item)").index(".box");
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box">
    <span class="item">my item</span>
</div>
<div class="box"></div>
```